# Build throws error in CLion using CMake

Tags: c, command-line, cmake, avr

Started a new C project in CLion with the following CMake configuration:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)

project(test)

include_directories("/usr/lib/avr/include")

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}")
set(SOURCE_FILES main.c)

add_executable(alma ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

And simple `main.c`

```
#define F_CPU 1000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/iom8.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void)
{
    DDRD |= _BV(PD5)|_BV(PD6);
    PORTD |= _BV(PD6);

    while (1) {
        PORTD ^= _BV(PD5)|_BV(PD6);
        _delay_ms(500);
    }
}
```

The following warning is thrown upon build

> warning: #warning "device type not defined"

I tried (went through a ton of google results)

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -mmcu=atmega8")
```

Which throws

> error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mmcu=atmega8’

Any help would be really, really appreciated since I have been googling around for hours but without any results...

Comment: So you pass -mmcu=atmega8 which is not recognized by your compiler. This is unrelated to command-line, CMake and CLion. Please update your question accordingly. You should check if you really use the compiler you think you are using. Obviously it is not support your target architecture.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to cross-compile. So you may need a toolchain file like [`cmake-avr`](https://github.com/mkleemann/cmake-avr). See also [here](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling).

Comment: @Florian thank you so much, this was the pitfall. It works! :) and a real help is always better than cheap talk (regarding previous comment).

Comment: @thEth Glad I could help. It was just a wild guess from having done my own share of cross-compiling with CMake and I admit that if I would have been the first to comment on your question I probably would have also asked about what you were trying to achieve. Regarding how your solution to the problem does look like, do you like to [answer it yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)?

Comment: @Florian That is probably another question - that would be a program for my AVR mcu. A new problem is on the horizon - how to make hex from CLion C excutable? Tried to use `xxd` but `avrdude` gets angry about the input (invalid input -1).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to cross-compile. So you may need a toolchain file like [`cmake-avr`](https://github.com/mkleemann/cmake-avr). See also [here](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling).
                    – Florian